# OpenFile command in Portal Not Working Same after Summer '18 upgrade

Tags: community, files, view

I have links in my community portal that launch files.  Since this weekend's upgrade to Summer '18 the files do not automatically launch.  Instead, users are taken to a file details page where there is a preview tab and a details tab.  I would like the previous functionality where the files automatically appear in full screen as viewable.  https://niimbl.force.com/s/?openFile=0696A0000017xUY is an example of a URL that would do this.  Thoughts?

Comment: It appears that the openfile part of the URL is being automotically changed to contentdocument.  The above URL changes to https://niimbl.force.com/s/contentdocument/0696A0000017xUY  This is a problem in that it doesn't launch the preview automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a new way to have a PDF automatically go into preview mode via a link...
​https://niimbl.force.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/0686A000001tjR0QAI?operationContext=S1